# Reference async Task without starting it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a class which needs a Parameter that needs to be invoked in other moment asynchronously

so lets say:

```
public class UnitTask {
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public Task JobToPefrorm { get; set;}
}

public static class GenericJobs {
    public static async Task ExecuteQuery(string query) {
        return await CodeToExecuteQueryAsync(query);
    }
}
```

so the idea behind this code is to generate multiple UnitTasks and run them in other part of the code. Is this possible? so far I tried this:

```
var ut = new UnitTask();
ut.Name = "Get People";
ut.JobToPerform = GenericJobs.ExecuteQuery("select * from people");
```

but this executes the task right away instead of just referencing the method.

Comment: You could make `JobToPerform` a `Func<Task>` and execute that at a later time. Any `Task` returned from an async method will already be started.

Comment: this actually worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not directly possible. The best workaround is to create factories:

```
ut.JobToPerformFactory = () => GenericJobs.ExecuteQuery("select * from people");
```

And `JobToPerformFactory` must be of type `Func<Task>`. The factory can then be invoked at any time to start a task. Store that task somewhere (possibly on the `ut` object) to get a handle to that operation and possibly `await` it later.