# Create async Task<T> without run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

How can I create a async Task but not run it right away?

```
private static async Task<string> GetString()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Finish";
}
```

---

```
Task<string> str = GetString();
```

This immediately starts the task.

Comment: That's not clear. What exactly do you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936526/reference-async-task-without-starting-it

Comment: Depending on your use case, a `Func<Task<string>>` might be helpful. There is no easy syntax to create cold tasks, so without this you're looking at something like Reactive Extensions (`Observable.Defer`), which has a bit of a learning curve. You could also start your task by waiting on something, like an event, so you can "start" it explicitly yourself.

Comment: It is interesting. So "out of the box", I can only create non-asynchronous tasks.
Task<string> tsk = new Task<string>(Test);

Comment: Related: [How to construct a Task without starting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066349/how-to-construct-a-task-without-starting-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dereferred excecution use Func.

```
private static Func<Task<string>> GetStringFunc()
    => GetString;
```

Thus:

```
var deferred = GetStringFunc();
/*whatever*/
var task = deferred();
```

Update: please have a look at `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: Start at the moment:
var task = deferred();
?

Comment: I didn't know about lazy! Thank!
var lazy = new Lazy<Task<string>>(() => GetString());
string res = await lazy.Value;

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cold Task by wrapping it in another Task.
The outer task creates the inner one without starting it.

```
//. If you don't call Start() and then await
//. Your code will never fire
public static async RunMe() {
    var coldTask = new Task<Task<string>>(GetString);
    // To start the task 
    coldTask.Start();
    // And then let it finish
    await coldTask;
}
// sharplab.io shows how C# compiles the async keyword
//.  into a state machine that creates the inner task without starting it.
```

Comment: You are awaiting the outer task, but not the inner task. How are you going to know that the inner task has completed?